# How do I properly set the annotation and query in Retrofit 2.0+?

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit

```
URL query string "q={city}" must not have replace block
```

I can't get this to work, I've tried several other variants but still get some form of exception.

```
public interface WeatherInterface {

    @GET("/weather?q={city}")
    Call<WeatherModel> getWeather(@Query("city") String city);

}
```

/////

```
public interface WeatherInterface {

    @GET("/weather")
    Call<WeatherModel> getWeather(@Query("q") String city);

}
```

And so on.

WeatherActivity.class

```
Call<WeatherModel> call = weatherInterface.getWeather("""CITYNAME""");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<WeatherModel> call, Response<WeatherModel> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    **///FIRST VARIANT FAILS HERE**
                    city.setText(response.body().getName());
                }
                **///SECOND VARIANT FAILES RESPONSE**
                else Log.d("No response", "RESPONSE");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<WeatherModel> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("fail", "fail");
            }
        });
```

EDIT:
Log.d(call.request().url().toString(), "CALL REQUEST URL");

I should share my solution too probably, I just logged the call url.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the to add my API KEY in the url. I shamefully withdraw my question.

Answer (score 0):

U can use this sample take example:

```
   public interface GitHubClient {  
        @GET("/users/{user}/repos")
        Call<List<GitHubRepo>> reposForUser(
            @Path("user") String user
        );
    }
```

For more samples just visit this [website](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client)

Comment: Yes, I checked the documentation but apparently my api key was missing. The log also shows how the url call looks like, if that helps anyone.